# Cisco 1242 WAP Configuration to broadcast SSIDs

Tags: cisco

OK, one would think this would be an easy question to answer. But searching online yields no results to our particular issue. We have Cisco WAPs that require configuration to broadcast the SSID of our private network. We already have a guest SSID, which is being broadcasted, and we have VLANs all set up on these devices. They are all working currently, we just need to broadcast the private SSID as well as the Guest SSID.

Why can't I find the commands or configuration options to turn broadcasting on? It's not obvious in the GUI, and the command line configuration is not obvious either. I know it's something simple.

Anyone got any ideas? If you need more information, please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I found it after some digging in the GUI. Looks like you have to set the global Guest Mode/Infrastructure SSID Settings to Beacon Mode = Multiple BSSID, and then for each SSID you have configured set the Set SSID as Guest Mode checkbox.

Not intuitive at all, but hey, it works.

Comment: Yeah, these things are a bit complex to set up.

Answer (score 1):

From the command line you can do **mbssid guest-mode** in each **dot11 ssid** configuration and then enter the **mbssid** command in the interface configuration mode for the Dot11Radio interface the SSIDs are configured on to enable multiple Basic Service Set Identifiers.  MBSSID also generates a modified AP MAC address for each SSID.  Had to enable this to get reliable WiFi connections with Apple devices since they would see a guest VLAN beacon from the same AP they were associated with and try to roam from the non-broadcast private VLAN to the guest.